# How do I get user location using Google Maps Platform SDK for iOS instead of CoreLocation

Tags: swift, google-maps, core-location, cllocationmanager, google-maps-sdk-ios

Does Google Maps Platform SDK for iOS have a way of showing the current user location? I know how to use CoreLocation to do that, but CoreLocation isn't working well for me.

I am using GPS to track the user walking and to calculate how much distance he is covering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro) and [Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/intro) for iOS use ⁠[Apple Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager), which you can also use directly to get location updates without having to use Google's iOS SDKs.

Currently, Google's iOS SDKs do not allow you to modify the location provider.

There's a feature request around being able to set another location provider in Google's issue tracker which I suggest starring to increase visibility and subscribe to future notifications:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116535597

Hope this helps!

Comment: Core Location doesn't work for me because it's not very accurate. I'm using it to track the distance that the user walks, and before the user moves, my code using Core Location already tracks that the user has walked .02 miles.

Comment: I see, let me give you a more extensive answer later. :)

Comment: That issue makes it sound like there is already a location provider for current location for Google Maps iOS SDK. I starred it anyhow.

Comment: I don't think the location provider used by the Places SDK would work for my purposes. I need exact coordinates instead of the coordinates of a defined location.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks! And you're right actually, all you'd need is Apple Core Location framework https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1 so will modify my answer to only include my edit for now but will get confirmation on this tomorrow. :)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. It looks like I'm left with Core Location.